# What % of horsepower in a turbine is used by the compressor section?

Tags: engine, engine-design

If a turbine generates 10,000 shaft horsepower, I am trying to understand how much horsepower has been used to compress the air.  So the turbine that generates 10,000 hp must in fact generate 10,000 hp plus X hp for the compressor.  What is the amount 15%, 25%, or what?  Thanks for your response.

Comment: Related: [How much power is drawn by a turbofan to power its own compressor?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/23955/1696)

Comment: I saw a figure for this once, and recall it was close to 75%. Obviousiy it varies over the decades of engine development that have occurred, but I think you are well on the wrong side of the 50% mark.